# Create workflow that contains the state machine action

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010 in order to use the SharePoint workflow.
I need to implement a "State Machine" action.

**so I assisted with:**

1. the Visual Studio program (I Create a project that uses the SharePoint 2010 Workflow).
2. and this post that explains how to program the state machine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508985.aspx

****this is my first time that I use those tool****

when I try to deploy the visual studio project I bump with that error:
[image: error message]

I do not know how to solve those error!!

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using the WF Workflow Designer for Visual Studio and Sharepoint, or are you using the *program* called SharePoint Designer?  I see both mentioned in your question